# Filter to exclude from results or clause to get all results without some

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm using hibernate search. Is it possible to exclude from fullTextQuery results with some field value ?
Example

Class Person with field firstname -> I want to get all results but without firstname:exampleName

I tried with filters but it in this case not return any results, the same thing is with replace MatchAllDocsQuery to BooleanQuery with clause MUST_NOT.

How to sovle this problem ?

Comment: Can you post the code you used with the MUST_NOT clause?  That should have worked here.

Answer (score 0):

A BooleanQuery should with  BooleanClause.Occur of MUST_NOT should worlk. Show what you have tried? Or you could use the Hibernate Search specific query DSL where there is a 'must(query).not()' clause. The latter looks like this:

```
Query query = queryBuilder.bool()
            .must( <your-query> )
            .not()
            .createQuery();
```